# Split string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I've a string

```
NULL ({ 8 9 36 37 }) John ({ 1 }) Loizou ({ 2 3 }) delves ({ 4 }) into ({ 5 })
```

how can I get?

```
NULL 8,9,36,37_
Jogn 1_
Loizou 2,3_
delves 4_
into 5
```

I using c#.

Comment: There is a pattern to what you are trying to do. Try to express in your native tongue then find the string ops to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort made on basic problem by op.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Here's one approach: https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/d89eb47ab7dcb3e269b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string start = @"NULL ({ 8 9 36 37 }) John ({ 1 }) Loizou ({ 2 3 }) delves ({ 4 }) into ({ 5 })";

string[] parts = start.Split(')');

string[] formattedParts = new string[parts.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string internalPart = parts[i].Trim();
    internalPart = internalPart.Replace("(", "");
    internalPart = internalPart.Replace(" ", ",");
    internalPart = internalPart.Replace(",{,", " ");
    internalPart = i < parts.Length - 2 ? internalPart.Replace(",}", "_") : internalPart.Replace(",}", "");

    Console.WriteLine(internalPart);
}
```

Comment: @KingKoro you're lucky someone answered your question. Next time you need to try also.